# Is it no longer possible to re-order structures in IDA?

Tags: ida, struct

In older versions of IDA, you could right-click a struct in the structure view and change its position in the list, making it easier to separate "internal" vs "external" structs. In the new 8.2 version (free edition), I don't see that option anymore. Has that ability been removed, or is there a different way to do it?

Comment: IDAPython still has the `idaapi.set_struc_idx` function, so if you weren't using the free one, you could use that. I suspect, though, that since the introduction of the folder view it's become irrelevant. This is because you can drag the items around in the folder list to re-position them.

However, another way to separate "internal" vs "external" structs is by using the type library via the "Local Types" window. If you don't have python scripting capabilities I'd suggest you use the local types instead.